# store as string as a list of number

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, parsing

I in python looking for a method that is capable of converting a string which could (different length) look like something like this. The string contains datapoints extracted from special file out of a 100 different files.

```
 [ 52.61236 -3.144785 -11.27863 -7.346569 11.27105 -2.408065 -10.35697 -15.61926 -2.353437 3.109831 -9.151857 -18.2364 -10.63264 
  56.55116 -9.186506 -13.75657 5.94078 5.96905 -1.483013 -4.259864 -12.57798 -0.9668677 -10.42454 13.35543 -9.19768 -14.42702 
  56.55116 -12.68435 -22.5432 12.2574 -1.100278 1.703274 6.538071 -3.648291 -1.31351 -6.617892 7.883823 1.777809 -20.30247 
  58.31721 -15.8642 -29.1799 -2.507436 9.061881 -8.988363 -2.703156 -9.803705 3.01952 -5.810421 -11.41331 6.092502 -14.42702 
  54.18788 -21.26995 -13.06826 -1.524487 7.294549 -6.622187 -6.594927 -7.723001 -0.4469042 -10.07848 1.881792 4.235661 2.776365 
  51.8246 -24.13182 1.875062 -0.08787012 -0.6584454 -6.10827 -5.686847 -17.57512 -2.70008 -7.425363 3.382299 2.605522 1.001098 
  47.8858 -16.81816 -5.772095 -7.346569 -0.2166124 -9.863102 -7.11383 -10.75736 -2.006795 -5.233656 2.45891 0.7017822 0.5999346 ]
```

to a list of numbers of numbers.   I am doing this in python so i guess there must be a handy library somewhere i can use of? but which one?

Comment: Please post a sample of the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to know where this rather strange kind of string is coming from, but if this is something you have and you cannot change it, here are several different approches.

#### Option 1

Pre-process the string by replacing the spaces between the numbers with commas and use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to load into a Python list:

```
In [1]: s = """ [ 52.61236 -3.144785 -11.27863 -7.346569 11.27105 -2.408065 -10.35697 -15.61926 -2.353437 3.109831 -
   ...: 9.151857 -18.2364 -10.63264 
   ...:   56.55116 -9.186506 -13.75657 5.94078 5.96905 -1.483013 -4.259864 -12.57798 -0.9668677 -10.42454 13.35543 -
   ...: 9.19768 -14.42702 
   ...:   56.55116 -12.68435 -22.5432 12.2574 -1.100278 1.703274 6.538071 -3.648291 -1.31351 -6.617892 7.883823 1.77
   ...: 7809 -20.30247 
   ...:   58.31721 -15.8642 -29.1799 -2.507436 9.061881 -8.988363 -2.703156 -9.803705 3.01952 -5.810421 -11.41331 6.
   ...: 092502 -14.42702 
   ...:   54.18788 -21.26995 -13.06826 -1.524487 7.294549 -6.622187 -6.594927 -7.723001 -0.4469042 -10.07848 1.88179
   ...: 2 4.235661 2.776365 
   ...:   51.8246 -24.13182 1.875062 -0.08787012 -0.6584454 -6.10827 -5.686847 -17.57512 -2.70008 -7.425363 3.382299
   ...:  2.605522 1.001098 
   ...:   47.8858 -16.81816 -5.772095 -7.346569 -0.2166124 -9.863102 -7.11383 -10.75736 -2.006795 -5.233656 2.45891 
   ...: 0.7017822 0.5999346 ]"""

In [2]: from ast import literal_eval

In [3]: import re

In [4]: l = literal_eval(re.sub(r"(?<=\d)\s+(?=[\-\d])", ",", s.strip()))

In [5]: l
Out[5]: 
[52.61236,
 -3.144785,
 -11.27863,
 ...
 2.45891,
 0.7017822,
 0.5999346]
```

---

#### Option 2 (probably the easiest)

`strip()` the square brackets, `split()` by space and use `float()` to convert individual substrings to floats:

```
In [13]: [float(item) for item in s.strip(" []").split()]
Out[13]: 
[52.61236,
 -3.144785,
 -11.27863,
 ...
2.45891,
 0.7017822,
 0.5999346]
```

---

#### Option 3

Use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to find all substrings with dashes, digits and dots, then "map" `float` function to get a list (in Python 2) of floats:

```
In [14]: map(float, re.findall(r"[\d\-.]+", s))
Out[14]: 
[52.61236,
 -3.144785,
 -11.27863,
...
 2.45891,
 0.7017822,
 0.5999346]
```

Comment: Added info.. I am not sure if I like this solution.. I process the string twice.. 
But i get an error when i execute it.

Comment: Why not just use `float`?

Comment: @CarltonBanks I'm not sure why do you use this regular expression in the code: `(?<=\d)\output_data+(?=[\-\d])` and not what was mentioned in the answer..

Comment: use `re` seems like overkill to me anyway. just `s.strip('[]').split()` sould work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga where? Do you mean it can be approached by stripping out `[` and `]` and splitting and then calling `float()` for every splitted substring? Yeah, this is one of the other possible approaches. Thanks.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga overkill or not, it's just one of the solutions - preparing the string for `literal_eval()` to do the "magic" :)

Comment: It works now.. Thanks for the solution.  
As this operation has to be done many time (Like a lot) doing it efficiently would be highly appreciated. So a different approach would also be appreciated.

Comment: @CarltonBanks okay, added 2 more options. Check them out. Thanks.